# Nested javascript onmousedown events

Tags: javascript, html

I would like different nested onmousedown events. For example, consider the following code:

```
<div id="parent" onmousedown="foo();">
  <div id="child1"> </div>
  <div id="child2"> </div>
  <div id="child3" onmousedown="bar();"> </div>
</div>
```

I'd like it so that clicking on any area that's inside the `parent` div, including `child1` and `child2`, would result in `foo()` being called, and if `child3` is clicked then `bar()` should be called instead.

My attempts so far have shown that the example above would call `foo()` when `child3` is clicked, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function bar(evt) {
  // Your stuff here
  if (typeof evt.stopPropagation != "undefined") {
    evt.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    evt.cancelBubble = true;
  }
}

</script>

<div id="parent" onmousedown="foo();">
  <div id="child1"> </div>
  <div id="child2"> </div>
  <div id="child3" onmousedown="bar(event);"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML:

```
<div id="parent" onmousedown="foo();">
  <div id="child1"> </div>
  <div id="child2"> </div>
  <div id="child3" onmousedown="bar(event);"> </div>
</div>
```

In javascript

```
function bar(event)
{
    // usual bar stuff
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm guessing that this is cross-browser compatible?